# Zapier - Zap, How to call an Action on a list one by one

Tags: zapier

I'm configuring a zap which  does the following:

1. Get a **list** of emails from an API endpoint.
2. Subscribe each record to Mailchimp

My problem here is that the subscriber email takes in a list of emails and this returns the following error message:

> Bargle. We hit an error creating a subscriber. :-( Error:  Invalid
>   Resource - Please provide a valid email address.

This is because Mailchimp aparently doesn't allow multple subscriptions in one single form.

So my question is, is there a way to perform an action per element in the list ?

Some sort of

```
emailList.foreach(function(email){
  performAction(email);      
})
```

Note that I cannot use the cli, is this possible with some sort of funnel action in zapier or maybe using the scrpting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

By default, when a trigger returns a top-level list of objects, subsequent actions occur for each. I'm not sure what type of trigger you're working with, but make sure it returns an object like this:

```
return [{email: 'email1@gmail.com'}, {email: 'email2@gmail.com'}, {email: 'email3@gmail.com'}]
```

and it should work as expected.